# Relationship between Gumbel and Frechet distributions

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, density-function, cumulative-distribution-functions, reparameterization-trick

I have a question regarding the Gumbel distribution. Based on the figure below, it appears that a form of the Fréchet distribution can be derived from it, using a log.

Variable $u_{i}$ represents an observed factor, and in contrast $z_{i}$ represents an unobserved factor that is i.i.d. And finally, $\mu$ represents the scale parameter of the Gumbel distribution.

Is it possible to provide the intuition or proof for obtaining this result?

[Gumbel to Frechet - Figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zQPYo.png)